# Is there anyway that I can add zoom-in and zoom out for Google Scatter chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have to add zoom in and zoom out in the google scatter chart,so I tried

```
  explorer: {
          actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset']
        }
```

in options, but it did not work..  Below is my code

```
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'speed(rpm)');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Toq(Nm)');
  data.addRows([
    <c:forEach items="${resultList }" var="result"  varStatus="status">
    [${result.mcuMotspd}, ${result.mcuMottoq}],
    </c:forEach>
  ]);

  var options = {
    chart: {
    },
    axes: {
        x: {
          0: { side: 'bottom', label: 'speed(rpm)'} // Top x-axis.
        },
        y: {
            0: { side: 'left', label:'toq(Nm)'} // Top x-axis.
          }
      },
      explorer: {
          actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset']
        }

  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Scatter(document.getElementById('chart_area'));

  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Scatter.convertOptions(options));
}
```

Please anyone help me for adding zoom in and out for the google scatter chart.. I cannot find information from google chart api reference..

Comment: there are several options that are not supported by _material_ charts (`google.charts.Scatter`), including `explorer`, see [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity #2143](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143) -- use a _classic_ chart instead --> `google.visualization.ScatterChart`

Comment: Hello, WhiteHat! Thank you for help!!!